# Undefined Variable data

Tags: php

Here is my code, i am using PHP inside HTML and this code was working fine a day ago but suddenly it stopped working and says that undefined variable 'data'  at line 25,27,29

```
<?php
require_once "databases.php";
if(isset($_POST['check']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['fullname'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];

        $db = new databases();
        $db->connection("localhost","root","","like_project");
        $query  = "UPDATE profile SET name='$name', city='$city', country='$country' WHERE profileID=2";
        $db->query($query);

    $data=$db->fetchRows("SELECT * FROM profile");
    //print_r($data);   
    }
    ?>
    <HTML>
    <Head><title>Profile</title></Head>
    <Body>
    <Center>
    <Form action='' method='POST'>
    <b>Name<br>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'fullname' value= "<?php echo $data[0]['name']; ?>"/><br>
    City<br>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'city' value= "<?php echo $data[0]['city']; ?>" /><br>
    Country<br>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'country' value= "<?php echo $data[0]['country']; ?> "/><br>
    Profile Picture<br>
    <input type = 'file' name 'dp' id='dp'/><br>
    Cover<br>
    <input type = 'file' name 'cover'/><br>
    <input type ='submit' value = 'Update' name = 'check'/>
    </Form>
    </Center>
    </Body>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: can you uncomment the print_r($data); and display the result of data?

Comment: @punitha subramani v unfortunately same result :/

Comment: @Tahir : can show what `fetchRows()` is doing..its code?

Comment: fetchRows() is not a function CI db. Are you getting data in  print_r($data);  ?

Comment: Nope, what am asking, I want to know what o/p you are receiving from $db->fetchRows.

Comment: Where u have defined the variables `$city` and all ?

Comment: just want to tell you all that this code was working fine a day ago but not now @ManishJ fetchRows() is my own function defined in database class that is written separetly

Comment: @Jenz it is defined above where i created object of databases()

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv it fetches all rows that are avilable in the database table

Comment: yes for that just print the data in outside the curl brace

Comment: @Jenz i have updated the code now you can see

Comment: please share code for `fetchRows()` too..

Comment: check if `profile` is not empty

Comment: thank u all i ahve figured out what i was doing wrong and specially @punithasubramaniv your last comment made me figured out what i was doing wrong :) thanks all

Comment: and please if anybody gave this question minus rating just remove them

Answer (score 1):

What I think is ....

```
$data=$db->fetchRows("SELECT * FROM profile");
```

its getting data more than one row.
As you are updating data for particular profile Id then why u selecting all data from profile table. As you are showing it in form so, you showing it for 1 user then why u fetching data for all.

If you want that then u need to put in LOOP to fetch details row wise.

Also, please write like

```
<?php if(isset($data[0]['name'])){ echo $data[0]['name'];} else {echo '';} ?>
```

in place of

```
<?php echo $data[0]['name']; ?>
```

Before, it might be working for you because. you may had only 1 row in ur db for fetching. 
But, now u have multiple.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $sql  = fetchArray"select * From Profile"

   foreach($sql as $row){
   $row[0] => mean first Value of array 
   or
   $row['name'];
   or
   $row->name;

    }
```

Comment: Welcome @Tahir Brohter